# Access Properties file from jsf page placed in application server

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jsf-1.2

I have a properties file in `jboss-as-7.1.1/modules/Myproperties/main/Myjar.jar/TRHBundle.properties` location of my application server.
Now how I can access it from `.xhtml` page?
When I have used proerties file in my project source folder then in `faces-config.xml`

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.edfx.trh.common.i18n.TRHBundle</base-name>
    <var>trhBundle</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

and use this from `.xhtml` page like

```
`<h:outputText value="#{trhBundle['home']}" />`
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: What is your file name `trhBundle.properties` or `TRHBundle.properties` ?

Comment: @Kalathoki Thanks for reply. Sory for this problem I have updated my question. `TRHBundle.properties` is my file name.

Comment: Is `com.edfx.trh.common.i18n`  your package name ? or else.....